# Icefaces: Network Connection Timeouts in IE only

Tags: timeout, icefaces

My application has a long running request that takes over a minute.  If I'm using Chrome or Firefox I just need to be patient.  If I use IE however, at the one minute mark I get the popup that says I've reached a Network Connection Timeout.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Internet Explorer time out is 1 minute. Since your process is a long-running one, IceFaces doesn't send the response and it times out.

You can avoid this by spawning a new thread for your long running process and returning the response immediately. IceFaces has plenty of polling or push options available to you to let your client know when the long-running process is done.